# Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable. Assume $f(n)\to2$ as $n\to\infty$, and $f'(x)\to0$ at infinity. Show $f(x)\to2$ at infinity.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be differentiable. Assume $f(n)\to2$ as $n\to\infty$, and $f'(x)\to0$ at infinity. Show $f(x)\to2$ at infinity.

I tried proving this using the mean value theorem but without luck. Any ideas?

I tried assuming by way of contradiction that $\lim_{x\to ∞}f(x)≠2$. That means that there is a neighborhood of $2$ such that there are infinitely many values of the function outside of this neighborhood.

So I apply the mean value theorem on $[n,t]$, where $t$ is a point such that $f(t)$ is outside the neighborhood of $2$.

So there is a $c∈(n,t)$ such that $f(t)-f(n)=f'(c)(t-n)$.

Since $t>n$ and $c>n$ then $\lim_{n\to ∞}t=∞$ and $\lim_{n\to ∞}c=∞$.

And I got stuck here.

Comment: Mean value theorem would be the way to do it, but it won't tell you much if you just apply it on $[n,n+1[$. Try assuming the conclusion is false. What does that tell you? Also helpful: every point in $\Bbb(R)$ is distance at most $1/2$ from an integer.

Comment: @KantigShoter, if you do not write in your question what you tried, your post will be closed by moderators very soon.

Comment: You are pretty close. I would do it directly from limit definition as I think it's more clear and easier. How can you bound the quantity $|f(x)-2|$? Theo's advice about mean value theorem and closeness to integers is pretty helpful to bound it

Comment: I am not sure how to bound it, but my goal is to find a sequence of $f'(x)$ that doesn't approach 0 at infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lfloor x \rfloor$ be the greatest integer smaller than $x$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f\left(\lfloor x \rfloor\right) = 2$, now use the mean value theorem
$$
\left|f\left(x\right)-f\left(\lfloor x \rfloor\right)\right|= \left|f'\left(c\right)\right|\left|x-\lfloor x \rfloor\right| \leq \left|f'\left(c\right)\right|.
$$
From this you can conclude.